# How to manage labels for clustered stacked bar reports in Microsoft Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I am building a bar graph report with clustered stacked bars (multiple categories), but axis labels don't seem to be working well for more than one category group. I want to be able to format the axis labels so I can always see all the labels for each category, but when I run the preview, the report comes up with truncated labels for the second and third row of labels (see the image with the red arrow). If I try formatting the labels from the Axis properties, then only the first row of labels will show the changes, but second and third row will keep unchanged. Labels for the secondary categories will show up fine if reducing the amount information presented, but still I cant format them like changing the angle or fonts.
[image][image: secind][image: third].

So far I have tried many changes from the axis properties but nothing works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community - this question isn't about code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to control the other Category Groups on an Axis.

It looks like there IS a way under the ChartAreas Collection's Category Axes Collection where there's Secondary axis properties but it's for a different axis at the TOP of the chart instead of bottom (sigh).

[image]

I think the only thing you can do is to concatenate the 3 Category Groups into 1 group.

```
=Fields!ShiftDate.Value & " - " & Fields!Crew.Value & " - " & Fields!Shift.Value
```

Comment: Thanks Hanover, I tried the Category Axes Collection already, and as you said, it does not do the trick.  I will try concatenating the categories and see if it works.